# How to fixture data for tests that are not in DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Let say I want to test my controller behavior, but it accepts JSON string via GET.

Right now I have var in my test class @testJson, but from time to time some unexpected stuff happens to those JSONS (bad char inside i.e.). So I want to add another test case.

But adding another var @problematicJson1 (and there could be more probably) doesn't seems like a good idea.

What's is the best way to keep "fixtures" like that? Should I keep'em in files and load them? Is there some fixture feature i don't know about that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those things are not fixtures.

You should use a neat feature of RSpec (if you are using RSpec at all) that allows to lazily define variables, so the actual variable is instantiated only when used by a specific "it", even if it is defined in an outer "context/describe" block.

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let

```
context "some context" do
  let(:testJson) { put your json inside the block }
  let(:otherJson) { {:my_json => textJson} } # this will use the defined testJson

  it "something" do
    testJson.should have_key "blah"
  end

  context "some internal context"
    let(:testJson) { something else }

    it "some other test" do
      otherJson[:my_json].should .... 
      # this will use the local version of testJson
      # you only have to redefine the things you need to, unlike a before block
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: No, I'm not using RSpec, but standard rails testing framework (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) but I was thinking about migrating to RSpec because I can not mock/stub methods (I think).